Fluids: Are Antisymm. Gradient $\frac{1}{2}(\nabla u - \nabla u ^\intercal)$ and Vorticity $\nabla\times u$ related?
In the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations, one gets an initial expression for the momentum equation that reads
$$ \rho\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u}\right)=\nabla\cdot\sigma+f$$
where $$\sigma = -p_{\text{stat}} \boldsymbol{\mathbb{I}}+ \mu \epsilon+\lambda(\nabla \cdot u)\mathbb{I}$$
and where

$p_{\text{stat}}$ ... static pressure
$\mu \epsilon$ ... viscous/shear stresses, with $\epsilon=\nabla_{s}u=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla u + \nabla u ^\intercal)$
$\lambda(\nabla \cdot u)\mathbb{I}$ ... bulk stress/bulk viscosity
$\mathbb{I}$ is the identity 2-tensor

Question: why is $\epsilon$ not the full gradient?
The explanation I found was, that the antisymmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(\nabla u - \nabla u ^\intercal)$ describes fluid rotation.
Is it related to the fluid vorticity, $$\nabla\times u?$$
Btw, I am aware, that after taking the divergence of $\sigma$, and assuming incompressibility, one gets $\nabla\cdot\nabla_s = \Delta$, but I am interested in understanding this anyways.
An equivalent question: why is
$$\sigma = -p_{\text{stat}} \boldsymbol{\mathbb{I}}+ \mu \nabla u+\lambda(\nabla \cdot u)\mathbb{I},$$
i.e. with the full velocity gradient, not correct?

The antisymmetric part $\mathbf{\Omega}=\frac12(\nabla \vec{u}-\nabla\vec{u}^{T})$ is indeed related to the fluid vorticity. We can see this by using index notation.
First, we have $\Omega_{ij}=\frac12(\partial_ju_i-\partial_i u_j)$. We can define a vector $\vec{\Omega}$ by $\Omega_k=\varepsilon_{ikj}\Omega_{ij}=-\varepsilon_{ijk}\Omega_k$.
Using the relation $\varepsilon_{ijl}\varepsilon_{ijk}=-2\delta_{lk}$, one can show $\varepsilon_{ijk}\Omega_{ij}=-2\Omega_k$.
However, by using the definition $\Omega_{ij}=\frac12(\partial_ju_i-\partial_i u_j)$, we have
$$\varepsilon_{ijk}\Omega_{ij}=\frac12 \varepsilon_{ijk}(\partial_ju_i-\partial_i u_j)=-\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_iu_j.$$
How does this relate to the vorticity $\vec{\omega}$? Well, we have
$$\omega_k=(\nabla\times\vec{u})_k=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_iu_j.$$
We can relate all three at last,
$$\omega_k=(\nabla\times\vec{u})_k=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_iu_j=-\varepsilon_{ijk}\Omega_{ij}=2\Omega_k.$$
We therefore have $\vec{\omega}=2\vec{\Omega}$. This is the relation to vorticity.
Now we see that $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is related to the vorticity - in particular, it is related to rigid-body rotations. We need to understand why this is important for the momentum equation. A rigid-body rotation of a fluid preserves the relative position of the fluid elements. The momentum equation deals with viscous stresses and a rigid-body rotation does not stress the fluid - relative motion of fluid elements next to each other is required for friction.
Edit:
In $n$ dimensions, the number of degrees of freedom of a vector is $n$. The number of degrees of freedom of an antisymmetric $n\times n$ matrix is $\frac12 n(n-1)$. Setting them equal to each other, we see that the only dimension where they have the same is $n=3$ (ignoring the trivial $n=0$). Therefore, a vector and an antisymmetric matrix in three dimensions can contain the same information.
For our purposes, the antisymmetric matrix $\mathbf{\Omega}$ has the three independent entries, which I shall call $\frac12\omega_1$, $\frac12\omega_2$, and $\frac12\omega_3$. The vector $\vec{\Omega}$ is simply writing these three entries as a vector and by the calculation above, we see that $2\vec{\Omega}=\vec{\omega}$, which explains my choice of name for the three independent entries.

Interesting. However I understand that the vector $\Omega_k$ is a very different object than the tensor $\Omega_{ij}$. What is $\Omega_k$? Your answer makes sense, arithmetically, but I still dont understand what the connection between vorticity and this tensor is. Could you elaborate?

@l'étudiant I have updated my answer, let my know if this helps!

Thank you. I can appreciate that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is special and that we can store the same information in the vector and matrix. But i have to disagree, $\vec\Omega$ is not just "simply writing these three entries as a vector". In fact, you chose to multiply $\Omega_{ij}$ by the $\epsilon$-symbol; this is equivalent to picking three entries from $\Omega_{ij}$ in a very particular (and a-priori arbitrary) order. And I would like to know the reason, why I should believe that this order is special and has physical meaning.

can you follow my point?

If you pick any other order, it won't transform as a vector under proper changes of coordinates.
